# How to get rid of glow on select elements without changing the drop down arrow in Firefox in MacOs?

Tags: css, macos, firefox, select

I am trying to get rid of the glow effect of `select`s in Firefox. I tried

```
select {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

which actually gets rid of it but changes the appearance of the drop down arrow.

Here is a pen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LQgzpW

[image]

**Edit**:

Setting `outline: none` seems not to have any effect on the glow.